# Laravel: Using an npm package - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

I'm struggling with installing and using a npm-based JS package: https://clipboardjs.com

So I ran the npm command :

```
npm install --save zenorocha/clipboardjs
```

I added this line into the `app.js` file :

```
require('clipboard');
```

I ran :

```
npm run dev
```

But afterwards I'm lost, I don't know how to actually load the package !

I keep getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ClipboardJS

Thank you in advance for your nice help !
Nic

PS : I need to make some precisions: I performed no other step than the nom install and adding a line into the app.js file... Are other moves necessary ?

Comment: It should be available in your `app.js`. The `Setup` or `Usage` sections from that link don't help?

Comment: I don't understand if I have to add a line like this one ; "<script src="dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>" or if the Laravel mix will do it for me...

Comment: could you please explain how you used this? I added the lines of the answer to app.js and recompiled, but now i dont know how to use it within my blade file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to assign it to the window object.

So change

`require('clipboard');`

to

`window.ClipboardJS = require('clipboard');`

I just created a new Laravel project and it worked for me.

Comment: Of course ! But I still get the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ClipboardJS" in the inspector...

Comment: @nicolas_geneva Updated my answer. Try that

Comment: And sorry to bother you but this goes into the resources/js/app.js file ?

Comment: Cool thx alot man :D

Answer (score 2):

Like the other response, using `window.ClipboardJS = require('clipboard');` is the first step you need that. But when you want to use it in your blade make sure your wrap your code with ClipboardJS object inside this event callback

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      // your ClipboardJS code here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone still faces the issue while adding `Clipboardjs` package in Laravel 10 -

### Installation of Package-

#### Install the  `clipboardjs` via npm -

```
npm install clipboard --save
```

#### Check if the package is added in `package.json` -

```
cat package.json
```

The dependency should be shown there -

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "clipboard": "^2.0.11"
  }
}
```

Now that we have confirmed that the package has been successfully installed and available in the laravel app, Let's go and initialize the package to use it.

#### Import Clipboard in `resources/js/app.js` -

Go to `resources/js/app.js` and import the `ClipboardJS` class from `clipboard` package

```
import ClipboardJS from 'clipboard';
```

#### Instantiate ClipboardJS class in `resources/js/app.js` -

Go to `resources/js/app.js` and instantiate the ClipboardJS class available from `clipboard` package

```
new ClipboardJS('#copyToKeyboard');
```

Here `copyToKeyboard` is the id of our copy button which is to be clicked

### Use the Clipboard in blade file -

#### Add copy button and target element in Laravel blade -

```html
<input type="text" readonly  id="slug" name="slug">
<span id="copyToKeyboard" data-clipboard-target="#slug">Copy</span>
```

> [!NOTE]
> Here `id="copyToKeyboard"` is the element for which we instantiated ClipboardJS class

> [!NOTE]
> Here `data-clipboard-target="#slug"` is the id of target element whose value is to be copied

> [!IMPORTANT]
> Do not forget to add  `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` in your app.blade.php or your parent blade layout so that the js and css is build automatically by vite server